# jQuery stop click event from bubbling when using $.get()

Tags: jquery, click, event-propagation

I have assigned a click event to a button, which retrieves a different HTML snippet and injects it into a DIV element using the .html(string) method.

```
$('#btnClose').click(function(){ 
   $.get('Content.html',function(data) {
      $('#EditCategory').html(data); 
   }); 
});
```

The Content.html page is as follows:

```
<button id="btnNewCategory" type="button">Add new category</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#btnNewCategory').click(alert('Test'));
</script>
```

Every time I click the '#btnClose' button the HTML snipper content is displayed but the alert('Test') is also fired. I've tried stopPropagation(),preventDefault() and return false; and have had no joy. Can anyone shed any light on what I'm doing wrong???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handler should be like this instead:

```
$('#btnNewCategory').click(function() {
  alert('Test')
});
```

What you currently have is firing `alert('Test')` *immediately* and trying to assign the result to a click handler, if you want it to run when clicked, use an anonymous function like I have above.

This isn't a propagation issue, [read here for a better understanding of that](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html), but a binding one :)

Comment: Well spotted !! I don't know how I missed it !